# Por Que quando vou rodar meu codigo aparece ( TypeError: Window.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Layout' )

Tags: python, pysimplegui

```
#Imports

import pyodbc

import random

import PySimpleGUI as sg

i=0

dados_conexao = (

    "Driver={SQL Server};"

    "Server=LOZANOTE\SQLEXPRESS;"

    "Database=SORTEIO_PY;"

)

#Multiplas Janelas

#janela0

def PostoSorteio():

    sg.theme('LightGray')

    layout0 = [

     [sg.Text("Escolha a Opção Desejada")],

     [],

     [sg.Button("Registrar participante"),
 sg.Button("Consultar tabela"),
 sg.Button("Remover participante"),
 sg.Button("Sortear"), sg.Button("Sair")],

     [],

    ]

    return sg.Window("janela0", Layout = layout0, finalize = True)

#janela1

def Registro():

    sg.theme('LightGray')

    layout1 = [
        [sg.Text('Nome do Participante')],
        [sg.Input()],
        [sg.Text('Numero do Participante')],
        [sg.Input()],
    ]
    return sg.Window("janela1", Layout = layout1, finalize = True)

    #janela2

def Tabela():

    sg.theme('LightGray')

    layout2 = [

        [sg.Text('Cadastrados')],

    ]

    return sg.Window("janela2", Layout = layout2, finalize = True)

    #janela3

def Remover():

    sg.theme('LightGray')

    layout3 = [

        [sg.Text('Quem deseja remover')],  

    ]

    return sg.Window("janela3", Layout = layout3, finalize = True)

    #janela4

def Sorteio():

    sg.theme('LightGray')

    layout4 = [

        [sg.Text('Numero sorteado foi!:')],

    ]

    return sg.Window("janela4", Layout = layout4, finalize = True)

 
 #Janelas Inicias

janela0, janela1, janela2, janela3, janela4 = PostoSorteio(), None, None, None, None

 #Loop de Eventos

while True:

    window, evento, valores = sg.read_all_windows()

 #Quando janela for fechada

    if window == janela0 and evento == sg.WIN_CLOSED or 'Sair':

        break

#Quando queremos ir pra outra janela

    if window == janela0 and evento == 'Registrar participante':

        janela1 = Registro()

        PostoSorteio.hide()
```

Esse é meu codigo atual, e não consigo descobrir o motivo de estar dando erro. sou novo nesse ramo. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Isso ocorre, porque o sg.Window não está reconhecendo o parâmetro `Layout`, troque o `Layout` por `layout`

Answer (score -2):

Verifique a Palavra chave descrita no erro "Layout" e, também se há ambiguidade no Método Construtor "*ini*"

Verifique a sintaxe "Layout" o erro direciona à esse detalhe.

Detalhe no seu Scritpt
return sg.Window("janela2", Layout = layout2, finalize = True)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).